# Spark cannot read files stored on AWS S3 in Frankfurt region (Ireland region works fine)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I run Apache Spark (2.11, 1.5.2) on a local machine using input files stored in AWS S3. If the files are stored in a bucket in the Ireland region (eu-west-1) it works fine.

But if I try to read files stored in an S3 bucket located in Frankfurt (eu-central-1) it fails with the error message:

**The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256**

How can I use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256?

The detailed error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/%2myfolder' XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message><RequestId>ECB53FECECD1C910</RequestId><HostId>BmEyVcO/eHZR3IO2Z+8IkEWOn189IBGb2YAgbDxhTu+abuyORCEjHyC14l6nIRVNNnQL2Nyya9I=</HostId></Error>
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.get(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.retrieveINode(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:214)
...
Caused by: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 GET failed for '/%2myfolder' XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message><RequestId>ECB53FECECD1C910</RequestId><HostId>BmEyVcO/eHZR3IO2Z+8IkEWOn189IBGb2YAgbDxhTu+abuyORCEjHyC14l6nIRVNNnQL2Nyya9I=</HostId></Error>
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.performRequest(RestS3Service.java:416)
    at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.performRestGet(RestS3Service.java:752)
```

The code is:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class S3Problem {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s3Folder = "s3n://mybucket/myfolder";

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> myData = sc.textFile(s3Folder).cache();
    long count = myData.count();

    System.out.println("Line count: " + count);
  }
}
```

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are provided as environment variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your path is set to s3://, I think it should be s3n://

Try changing that, along with using these authentication parameters:

```
val hadoopConf=sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId","key")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","secret")
```

Alternatively you could try using s3a:// but you'll have to include the hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk jar files into your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Sorry I was using actually s3n:// when the problem occured. I have changed the description. Using s3a:// also did not help. Same problem: `The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.` I used hadoop-aws:2.7.1 and aws-java-sdk:1.7.4.

Comment: Ok if you're using the AWS Java SDK, try: `System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");`  or check this link [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html]

Comment: If have already tried using `System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");`but the error remains. I am not sure if aws-java-sdk:1.7.4 is already prepared for Frankfurt region as the region was established after releasing 1.7.4. But I cannot use newer versions of aws-java-sdk as that requires Hadoop 2.8.0 which is not release yet (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12420).

Comment: That's surprising, I'm using aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.27.jar on hadoop 2.6, can you downgrade your Hadoop to 2.6.x?

Comment: I finally got it running with hadoop-aws:2.7.1 and aws-java-sdk:1.7.4. Using s3a:// I had to use `System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");` then setting the region / endpoint using `conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com");` and setting access key with `conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "<access key>");` and `conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "<secret access key>");`

Comment: Well done for figuring that out! Seems a bit of a gap in the documentation from AWS

Comment: Running spark 1.6.1 with aws-java-sdk 1.7.4 and hadoop-aws 2.7.2 i got s3a scheme working as follows:
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
ctx.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"); Notice the s3-eu-west iso s3.eu-west because otherwise there is no ssl certificate matching the (sub)domain.
ctx.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "...");
ctx.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "...");

Answer (score 10):

Putting together Ewan and windsource's answers into a working (at least for me) complete script for PySpark:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark

spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("Spark") \
    .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Set the property for the driver. Doesn't work using the same syntax 
# as the executor because the jvm has already been created.
spark.sparkContext.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")

spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.proxy.host", "***")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.proxy.port", "8080")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "***")
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "***")

test = spark.sparkContext.textFile('s3a://my-bucket/test')
print(test.take(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankfurt region is using auth v4, an easier way to use s3n impl for s3 path, is set something like this in core-site.xml (use s3n for both s3 and s3n path)

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value>
</property>
```

but, you should really think about upgrade s3 impl to `s3a`, it is using aws sdk.

you need to put hadoop-aws jar and aws-java-sdk jar (and third-party jars in its package) into your CLASSPATH.

hadoop-aws: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/

aws-java-sdk: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/

then in core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>
```